# Django: Count Items and ordered by Parent Category and Child Categories

Tags: django

I hope someone can help. I want to achieve something similar to what you see on a classified site or blog, where you have a sidebar with categories(parent categories with child categories) and a count of how many classified ads or blog posts in that parent category and child category. So as to look like this:

[image: Sidebar: Showing a count of all ads in the parent category and in the children categories]

Here is my model

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=False, editable=False)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='child_set')

class Classified(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='categories')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, unique=True, blank=False)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, blank=False, default=0)
    description = models.TextField(null=False, blank=True, editable=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    sold = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, null=False, editable=False)
```

Here is my template tag:

```
class Categories(template.Node):
    def render(self, context):
        categories = Category.objects.filter(parent=None).order_by('parent')
        context['categories'] = categories
        return ''
```

Here is my template filter for getting the count:

```
# Parent Category Count
@register.filter
def parent_category_count(value):
    count = Classified.objects.select_related().filter(category__in=Category.objects.filter(parent=value)).exclude(sold=True).count()
    return count

# Child Category Count
@register.filter
def child_category_count(value):
    count = Classified.objects.select_related().filter(category=value).exclude(sold=True).count()
    return count
```

Here is my template:

```
{% regroup categories by parent as cat_list %}

{% for parent in cat_list %}
    <ul class="category">
        {% for item in parent.list %}
            <li class="parent-category-item">
                {% block parent-category %}
                    {% if item|parent_category_count %}
                        <span class="category-count">{{ item|parent_category_count }}</span>
                    {% else %}
                    {% endif %}
                <a {% if item.name == category %}class="parent selected"{% else %}class="parent"{% endif %} href="{% url classifieds_home %}{{ item.slug }}/">{{ item.name }}</a>
                {% endblock %}
            </li>
            <ul {% if item.name == category %}class="child-categories"{% else %}class="child-categories hide"{% endif %}>
                {% for i in item.child_set.all %}
                    <li class="child-category-item">
                        {% block category_child %}
                            {% if i|child_category_count %}
                                <span class="category-count">{{ i|child_category_count }}</span>
                            {% else %}
                            {% endif %}
                        <a {% if i.name == child_category %}class="child selected"{% else %}class="child"{% endif %} href="{% url classifieds_home %}{{ item.slug }}/{{ i.slug }}/">{{ i.name }}</a>
                        {% endblock %}
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

I've tired using a template tag and that works with everything except the count. I tired using a custom template filter to get the count on each category, but it takes a long time (277 queries in 141.91ms).

So I know the filter count is causing the database to be hit multiple times, which isn't good. Everything would work if the child count would work as the parent count loads fast, but I'm guessing that's more to do with there being less parent categories.

I've also tired using raw(), extra() and annotate() in Django but to no avail, unless of course I'm not doing it right. I'm not sure what is the best approach at this point, but I'm sure someone has done this before and I won't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: So far most of the feedback I've gotten has been to try [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt) - So I'm going to give that a go. And also, while I though this was a simple menu, it's more of a recursive tree as I've been told :)

Comment: check in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501149/django-order-by-count-of-a-foreignkey-field